# Sorting date field with format doesn't work

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 7.0 with [ES NodeJS](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js). I mapped the field with type date and format. I tried to sort with date desc, the latest object placed at index 3 instead of first.

**Mapping**

```
client.indices.putMapping({
  index: 'property',
  body: {
    properties: {
      'created_at': { 
        'type': 'date', 
        "format":"YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.000'Z'", 
        "ignore_malformed": true 
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**Search Sort**

```
client.search({
    index: 'property',
    body: {
      from : req.body.start,
      size : req.body.length,
      query : {
        "bool": {
          "must": []
        }
      },
      sort: [
        { 'created_at': { 'order': 'desc' }}
      ]
    }
})
```

**Result**

```
[
  { "created_at": "2019-05-03T17:19:59.000Z" },
  { "created_at": "2019-05-03T17:06:26.000Z" },
  { "created_at": "2019-05-08T16:00:34.000Z" }
]
```

**Expected Result**

```
[
  { "created_at": "2019-05-08T16:00:34.000Z" }
  { "created_at": "2019-05-03T17:19:59.000Z" },
  { "created_at": "2019-05-03T17:06:26.000Z" }
]
```

Comment: Are you sure you have this as a sortable column?  In case you put order ASC do you get the exact same result?

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge Is different result with asc

Comment: And when ordering by ASC I assume you get { "created_at": "2019-05-08T16:00:34.000Z" } first and { "created_at": "2019-05-03T17:19:59.000Z" } last, correct?

Comment: Querying ES directly shows order correctly?